# how to remove the duplicate innerlists from mainlist.in java?

Tags: java, list

```
list<list<Integer>ms2=new ArrayList<>();
for(int a=0;a<ms2.size()-1;a++)
{
     List<Integer>arr=new ArrayList<Integer>(ms2.get(a));
     for( int n=a+1;n<ms2.size();n++)
     {
          List<Integer>arr1=new ArrayList<Integer>(ms2.get(n));
          if(arr.equals(arr1))
          {

             ms. remove(n);//here ms is the same list as the (ms2)just a copied version.
          }
      }
  }
```

For example, consider a list of list in Java as:
`[[1,1,1],[23,4,5],[1,1,1]]`. Now, the output: `[[23,4,5],[1,1,1]]`. How do we do this, any idea?

The above code is not working for input: `[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0]]`. Output: `[[0,0,0,0]]`, but for me it is throwing an error.

Comment: Why is `[1,1,1]` not in the output for the first input?

Comment: I had to read it a few times, but I think you're saying: with input of `[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0]]` you are expecting to see output of `[[0,0,0,0]]`, but instead an error occurs. What is the error? Please post enough code + input for others to reproduce what you're seeing: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i am getting a run time error . index of bound..

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a `Set` from the list of lists to remove duplicates and convert it back to a `List` (if necessary).

```java
List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(1,1,1),List.of(23,4,5),List.of(1,1,1));
Set<List<Integer>> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(list); // remove duplicates, preserving order
List<List<Integer>> list2 = new ArrayList<>(set); // convert back to List
```

Comment: I understand your thought process,but if there are some N inner lists then how would you write the first line of your code?

Comment: @ananthaPuneethchowdary That's just the input data, which you should already have.